# FOR LOOP printing value more than array size without core dump

Tags: c, for-loop, coredump

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int numbers[2]={0};
   int i=0;
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
       numbers[i]=1;
       printf("<%d>\n",numbers[i]);
     }
  return 0;
}
```

For loop printing Infinite value if input is less than 3. it must give core dump because the assign size of array is 2 which could contain maximum 3 values. No core dump received. I don't know why but Loop is printing proper values

Answer (score 1):

Per ISO C standard accessing out of bounds is an [Undefined Behavior.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)